# How to sort string with a number in aggregation using mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Actually I'm doing sorting for these documents in this `name` variable is in lowercase and uppercase values. If i apply sorting for these `name` variable not working properly.

Then I change `name` variable to lowercase using `{ $toLower: '$name' }` then sorted fine. then same lower case applying for `position` variable then it is converting number to string.

In this case sorting is not working properly i cannot able convert or checking type of variable in  aggregation. can you suggest how to check variable type in aggregation.

```
{
    'name': 'vvvvvv',
    'slug': 'vvvvvv',
    'position': NumberLong(4),
    'status': NumberLong(0),
    'parent': ObjectId("56b9f1948eb55dfc17cf33f0"),
    'category_filter': [  ],
    'seo': {
        'title': 'vvvvvv',
        'keyword': 'vvvvvv',
        'description': 'vvvvvv'
    } 
},
{
    'name': 'Person',
    'slug': 'vvvvvv',
    'position': NumberLong(4),
    'status': NumberLong(0),
    'parent': ObjectId("56b9f1948eb55dfc17cf33f0"),
    'category_filter': [  ],
    'seo': {
        'title': 'vvvvvv',
        'keyword': 'vvvvvv',
        'description': 'vvvvvv'
    } 
}
```

*Aggregation Query:*

```
[
    { $project: {
        _id: 1,
        items: { $size: "$items" },
        status: 1,
        total: 1,
        shop: 1,
        customer: 1,
        dname: { $cond: { 
            if: { 'position': { $type : "string" }}, 
            then: { $toLower: '$'+sorted },
            else: '$'+sorted 
        }}
    }
]
```

Comment: This should be done while building your query in the language you are using rather than in the aggregate query itself. Thus, while building your sort stage, you should decide on whether to add the toLower or not depending on the type. Therefore, you will have queries that include the toLower and some that don't depending on your application

Comment: I am confused here about what you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate?